# Mapping to get last make command and execute it again

Tags: key-bindings

I want to map an action that repeats the last make command.

Ideally, such a mapping would work also in insert mode (i.e. it would automatically switch to command mode.)

Also, it would be nice, if such an action also automatically saved the buffers with unsaved changes in them.

Basically, this would automate steps like:

```
Ctrl+[
:w
:ma
Arrow-Up
Return
```

Such steps could be mapped to <kbd>F9</kbd>, for example.

Ok, saving all buffers with unsaved changes (e.g. when in split-window mode) probably complicates the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to translate your keystrokes into a mapping:

```
nnoremap <F9> :wa<CR>:ma<Up><CR>
imap <F9> <Esc><F9>i
```

Here `<CR>` means carriage return.  You can also use `<Enter>` but that's longer to type!

The `imap` jumps out of insert mode with `<Esc>`, invokes the normal-mode F9 mapping, then goes back into insert mode with `i`.  We can't make it a "noremap" because we want it to expand the other F9 mapping.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `:wa`, thought writing all changed buffers would be more complicated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Ingo Karkat's [Redocommand plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1661) which allows to call the last command matching a pattern.

The idea would be to add the following function to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! LastMake()
    bufdo w
    Redocommand :make
endfunction
```

In this function `bufdo w` saves all unsaved buffers and the second line use Redocommand to call the last `make` function.

Then you create the folowing mappings (add these two lines to your `.vimrc`)

```
nnoremap <F9> :call LastMake()
inoremap <F9> <Esc>:call LastMake()
```

which will allow you to use <kbd>F9</kbd> in normal and insert mode to call the function.

**EDIT** As @Jjaderberg  pointed it out in comments, `bufdo` will change the current buffer which could be an issue if your `make` command does use an absolute path. So a good solution is to replace it by `wall` (for Write All) as @joeytwiddle suggested to get the same result without changing the current buffer. (Thanks to both of you for your comments) :

```
function! LastMake()
    wall 
    Redocommand :make
endfunction
```

Comment: `:bufdo` will make last processed buffer the current buffer. If the `:make` command that you are redoing refers to "current buffer" or "file of current buffer", or if making the last processed buffer the current buffer involves changes to 'pwd' or other pertinent options you may end up running a different command than intended.

Comment: Instead of `bufdo w` you could `wall` and avoid changing buffer.

Comment: Or use this [`:BufDo`](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/77f1e3e79c89105716f2e9cd7d6414b3237d9e05/.vim/plugin/joeycommands.vim?ts=2#L161-L167) which returns you back to your starting window.